# Select the first row and aggregate within a group_by in a data frame in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have the following data

```
 df <-  tibble::tribble(
      ~V1,          ~V2,              ~V3,      ~V4,       ~V5,
    "CTV10016020", "PoP", "2020-06-08 01:50:07", 220L,   "Music",
    "CTV10016020", "PoP", "2020-06-08 01:53:45",   8L,    "Music",
    "CTV10016020", "PoP", "2020-06-08 01:53:53", 133L,   "Music",
    "CTV10016020", "PoP", "2020-06-08 01:56:05", 234L,   "Music",
    "CTV10016020", "PoP", "2020-06-08 01:59:57",   0L, "Control",
    "CTVM11011420", "Game", "2020-06-08 02:03:00",   0L, "Control",
    "CTVM11011420", "Game", "2020-06-08 02:03:00",  10L,    "Music",
    "CTVM11011420", "Game", "2020-06-08 02:03:07", 116L,   "Music",
    "CTVM11011420", "Game", "2020-06-08 02:05:01",  32L,   "Audio",
    "CTVM11011420", "Game", "2020-06-08 02:05:32", 208L,   "Music",
    "CTVM11011420", "Game", "2020-06-08 02:08:36",  42L,   "Audio"
    )
```

I want to group_by V1 and V2 , keep the first V3 record and calculate sum for V4.

Expected output from sample data:

```
   V1           V2    V3                   total               
   <chr>        <chr> <dttm>              <int>             
 1 CTV10016020   PoP   2020-06-08 01:50:07   595 
 2 CTVM11011420  Game  2020-06-08 02:03:00   408
```

My attempt: I tried `dplyr::first` but I think I am using it in a wrong way.

```
 df %>% 
   mutate(V3= as.POSIXct(V3, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS", tz = "Europe/Helsinki")) %>% 
   group_by(V1, V2) %>% 
   dplyr::mutate(
     first = dplyr::first(V3)) %>%
   summarize(total_duration = sum(V4))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OP's method should work fine if we remove the `mutate` step after the `group_by` and use that in `summarise` because after the `summarize`, we get the only column used in `summarise` along with any grouping columns i.e. the `mutate` to get the `first(V3)` is not getting into the output

```
library(dplyr)
 df %>% 
    mutate(V3= as.POSIXct(V3, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS", tz = "Europe/Helsinki")) %>%
    group_by(V1, V2) %>%
    summarise(V3 = first(V3), total = sum(V4))
# A tibble: 2 x 4
# Groups:   V1 [2]
#  V1           V2    V3                  total
#  <chr>        <chr> <chr>               <int>
#1 CTV10016020  PoP   2020-06-08 01:50:07   595
#2 CTVM11011420 Game  2020-06-08 02:03:00   408
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `dplyr`

```
df %>%
  group_by(V1, V2) %>%
  mutate(total=sum(V4)) %>%
  select(-c(V4, V5)) %>%
  distinct() %>%
  filter(V3==first(V3))
```

gives you

```r
# A tibble: 2 x 4
# Groups:   V1, V2 [2]
  V1           V2    V3                  total
  <chr>        <chr> <chr>               <int>
1 CTV10016020  PoP   2020-06-08 01:50:07   595
2 CTVM11011420 Game  2020-06-08 02:03:00   408
```